# What is the phonological error pronouncing /θ/ as /s/ called?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

How can I explain the error of pronunciation in the sentence

> I sink I'm going to bed

where the word pronounced *sink* is actually *think*?

Comment: Hi user 98676. This is EL&U. ELL is our sister site for those who are learning the English Language.  Follow the link http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there are two ways of pronouncing -th *correctly*. The **voiced dental fricative** /ð/ as in *this* and *mother*, and the **voiceless dental fricative** /θ/  as in *thing* and *thin*. But many teachers will simply say *voiced* and *unvoiced*.

The -th in *think* is *unvoiced*, meaning, only air passes through the mouth

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8th%E2%9F%A9) explains what the OP refers to "error of pronunciation" can be called

> **th-alveolarization**
>   In rarer or older varieties of African American Vernacular English, /θ/ may be pronounced [s], as in bathroom [ˈbæsɹum].
>   [...]
>   Children with a **lisp**, however, have trouble distinguishing **/θ/ and /ð/ from /s/ and /z/** respectively in speech, using a single /θ/ or /ð/ pronunciation for both, and may never master the correct sounds without speech therapy. The lisp is a common speech impediment in English. Foreign learners may have parallel problems. In English popular culture **the substitution of /z/ for /ð/** is a common way of parodying a French accent, but in fact learners from very many cultural backgrounds have difficulties with English dental fricatives, usually caused by interference with either sibilants or stops. Words with a dental fricative adjacent to an alveolar sibilant, such as *clothes*, *truths*, *fifths*, *sixths*, *anesthetic*, etc., are commonly very difficult for foreign learners to pronounce.

For further information please see this question on EL&U
 [Is there a rule for pronouncing “th” at the beginning of a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94835/is-there-a-rule-for-pronouncing-th-at-the-beginning-of-a-word)

Comment: There is a third way, namely /t/, as in Thames or Thailand.

Comment: @painfulenglish You are correct, it's in the link I posted.